# Machinability index for ferrous and nonferrous material

Tags: mechanical-engineering, machining, material-science

What are the machinability index for ferrous and non-ferrous materials?

Please help me so that I can learn more about it. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure its *machinability indes* and not **machinability index**?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a detailed list for metals both ferrous like steel and cast iron and, nonferrous like copper and their alloys Machinability Rating Chart.

[machinabilty index](https://www.a-i-t.com/cnc-machining-services/machinability-rating-chart)

Answer (score 2):

**Machinability index** is measure for cutting processes which shows how easy it is to remove material. It is used by comparing the cutting speed to a reference value for steel.

I.e.:

- you try to find what is the speed that a cutting tool will last 20 minutes while cutting a given material. $V_m$
- you compare $V_m$ with the reference speed $V_r$ (which uses steel as a reference).

There is also **Machinability rating** which is based on a similar idea, i.e.  the cutting speed you can use with respect to a reference speed

$$\text{machinability index} = \frac{V_c}{V_r}\cdot 100\%$$

The reference cutting speed is based on B1112 steel.

If it is easy to remove material then, the index goes up. For example, diamond would have an index close to zero, while mg alloys have a much higher index.

It can be used for most processes that involve removal of material, with a cutting tool (such as milling, lathing etc).